# Venetion Typeface for Web similar to Adobe Jensen Pro?

Tags: web-fonts, font-recommendation

I am looking for a free web compatible (e.g. should be possible to use with CSS3) Venetian style typeface. Any idea if there exists one.

That would be ideally a typeface looking similar to [Adobe Jensen Pro](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/jenson/)

Comment: By web compatible do you mean you're looking for a embeddable webfont?

Comment: If the latter, you can narrow your myfonts search to include venetian faces with webfont license options: http://www.myfonts.com/search/tag:Venetian/webfonts/?view=list

Answer (score 1):

Try `Baskerville Book Italic`. It looks awesome and I plan to use it for my portfolio. Example:

[image]

Available as a web font here: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/baskerville-mt/italic/buy.html

Comment: Where can you obtain a webfont license for it?

Comment: @ DA01 Are you skilled in the art of searching the web?!

Comment: I am. But that's not an answer to a question on SE.

Comment: @DA01 I have seen it on a web site and it renders very well as a web font. I would not mention the URL, because people might steal it.

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't being clear. I was suggesting that this would be a better answer if you were to actually provide a source for a webfont license for this typeface as (I think) that is what the OP was looking for (though that's not entirely clear).

Comment: @DA01 http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/baskerville-mt/italic/

Comment: I updated your answer with that info. I think that makes it a much better answer! (Though note that I removed the Berthold reference as the link is going to the Monotype version)

Comment: @DA01 Here is a link to Berthold version:
http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/berthold/baskerville-book-be/book-italic/

Comment: Doesn't look like Berthold offers web licenses...at least not on myFonts.

Comment: boo to not posting a link because people might steal it...this is the internet

Comment: @albert Boo to you too jr-associee.com

Comment: boo to not making sense in a boo ;)